# Enable Voice Control. AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I try to create an Apple Script to Enable Voice Control in a Mac.

This is in: System Preferences > Accessibility > Voice Control > Enable Voice Control

I think I get close. But I do not know how to call the left menu "Voice control"

This is what I have tried and do not work:

```
tell application "System Events"
    click checkbox "Enable Voice Control" of window "Voice Control" of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences" of application "System Events"
end tell
```

Comment: Why the negative point? What have I done wrong? How can I improve the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked in the comments if there was another way to get the solution. Here's a way to revise your code. First, I will explain the solution, step by step.

**Update**: This if statement, as pointed out in user3439894's very helpful comments below, is actually necessary, for several reasons. It should always be included.

```
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    quit application "System Preferences"
    delay 1
end if
```

1. This is done so the script will not fail if it is running. Note that the user also pointed out that killall should be used to ensure that the process completely terminates.
2. It allows for predictability in the behavior of the application.

user3439894 also pointed out that I should add this code block, in case there is a timing issue, resulting in the application trying to reopen while it is in the process of closing.

```
repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat
```

Next, in this snippet, you click the Accessibility button in System Preferences

```
tell application "System Events"
    click button "Accessibility" of scroll area 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences" -- click the Accessibility button
    delay 2 -- while loads
```

Next, you select the Voice Control row in Settings.

```
    select row 13 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
    delay 0.2 -- delay while page loads
```

And finally, click the checkbox. As I explained in the comments, groups are used to organize elements.

```
    click checkbox "Enable Voice Control" of group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
end tell
```

Full (updated) code:

```
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

activate application "System Preferences"
tell application "System Events"
    click button "Accessibility" of scroll area 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences" -- click the Accessibility button
    delay 2.0 -- delay while page loads
    select row 13 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
    delay 0.2 -- delay while page loads
    click checkbox "Enable Voice Control" of group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"

end tell
```

Corrections I made to your code:

1. You cannot reference elements from windows that are not already opened in an app (like you did with the checkbox "Enable Voice Control" of window "Voice Control" of window "Accessibility"), so first I opened the Accessibility window (click a button) -> Voice Control Window (select the row), and then found/clicked the checkbox.
2. Then, I looked at the hierarchy of the elements to figure out where the *checkbox* is in that Voice Control Window. I found out that it is inside group 1 of window 1 (Voice Control Window), so I clicked it.
3. I also added delays (the app needs time to load after every click/select).

Also, here is how I figured out where the elements are.

- If you don't already use it, there is this built-in app called *Accessibility Inspector* to help you locate elements.
- You can also use ***get*** in applescript. For example,

  ```
   tell application "System Events"
       get buttons of scroll area 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
   end tell
  ```

  would return:

  > ... button **"Accessibility"** of scroll area 1 of window "System Preferences" of application process "System Preferences" of application "System Events", button **"Screen Time"** of scroll area 1 of window "System Preferences" of application process "System Preferences" of application "System Events",...
- Another example:

  ```
   tell application "System Events"
       get UI elements of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
   end tell
  ```

  and here's some of the output

  > **...scroll area 1** of window "System Preferences" of application process "System Preferences" of application "System Events", **toolbar 1** of window "System Preferences" of application process "System Preferences" of application "System Events..."

A very helpful tool.

Comment: It works well. Thank you. I am a beginner and there are some things I do not understand. "group 1" makes reference of the previous block of code, is that right? Can you explain how group works

Comment: A group, to the best of my knowledge, is just an area that contains a bunch of different elements, which you can refer to from inside the group. Groups are there to make things more organized. In the code above, I was referencing the first window of System Preferences, then the first group of elements within that window (which happens to contain the checkbox), then the checkbox itself, which is clicked.

Comment: Just to learn: is there any other way to call the "window Voice Control"? Is there any way that my code could be repaired?

Comment: I'll update my answer when I get a chance, to show you another way

Comment: RE: "-- this part is not always necessary, but is recommended for performance" -  Please look at my answer to the question you asked the other day.  I submit that the top two _code blocks_ are indeed necessary and should always be used when **UI Scripting** with **System Events** and **System Preferences** for the following reasons... First _code block_... Checks to see if **System Preferences** is running and if yes, then close it. This is done so the script will not fail if it is running and a _modal sheet_ is showing, hence the use of '`killall` as `quit` fails when done so, if it is. Cont.

Comment: This is also done to allow default behaviors to be predictable from a clean occurrence. -- Second _code block_... Makes sure **System Preferences** is not running before opening it again. Otherwise, there can be an issue when trying to reopen it while it is actually closing. (It may be a timing/race issue, but I've implemented these based on many years of the **UI Scripting** of **System Preferences**) IMO All **UI Scripting** using **System Events** and **System Preferences** should always start with those two _code blocks_ for the reasons expressed.

Comment: I updated the answer. Thank you for taking the time to correct it. I wasn't aware of the necessity of those statements.

Comment: Thank you very much. For other people: in my case it was: select row 13 nor 12

Comment: In my case, it was select row 12. I suppose that the difference is related to the operating system. In any case, 12 goes to the right place but, in fact, it is the 9 element in the scroll row